# Op type not registered 'BatchMatMulV2' in binary running

Tags: docker, tensorflow, server, inference, tensorrt

Description

when try to run my tensorflow savedmoel on TRTIS . it failed to start up with below error:

failed to load 'trt_model' version 1: Not found: Op type not registered 'BatchMatMulV2' in binary running on fa60ca095bbf. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) tf.contrib.resampler should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.

TRTIS Information
I am using TRTIS 1.5.0

container 19.06
CUDA Version 10.1.24
Driver Version: 418.87.01

OS : ubuntu 16.04

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Expected behavior
The is the output of runing cmd line "curl localhost:8000/api/status"

```
id: "inference:0"
version: "1.3.0"
uptime_ns: 235795201147
model_status {
key: "trt_model"
value {
config {
name: "trt_model"
platform: "tensorflow_savedmodel"
version_policy {
all {
}
}
input {
name: "input"
data_type: TYPE_INT32
dims: -1
}
input {
name: "input_lengths"
data_type: TYPE_INT32
dims: -1
}
input {
name: "split_infos"
data_type: TYPE_INT32
dims: -1
}
output {
name: "out0"
data_type: TYPE_FP32
dims: -1
}
instance_group {
name: "trt_model"
count: 1
gpus: 0
kind: KIND_GPU
}
default_model_filename: "model.savedmodel"
}
version_status {
key: 1
value {
ready_state: MODEL_UNAVAILABLE
}
}
}
}
```

If the model deployment is ok , the reday_status will be "MODEL_READY", so how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

TRTIS 19.06 wasn't built with the tensorflow.contrib ops, looks like this should be fixed in TRTIS >= 19.07 per this PR: https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorrt-inference-server/pull/421

See this related thread for more discussion: https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorrt-inference-server/issues/855

Answer (score 0):

you can use `tf.raw_ops.BatchMatMul()` replace `tf.matmul()`
i use tf1.14 train and predict with tf1.12
its work